# In Google App Script, how can I append a row to a new sheet when the data contains commas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

In Google Sheets (using Google App Script), I am creating a script that checks row by row for whether there is a value in a specific column. If there is no value in that column, then I would like to copy-paste the row into a new sheet. In the code below, I do this by joining the current row into a 1 dimensional array, splitting it by comma, and then appending it to the destination sheet. However, some of my data has commas in it, causing the pasted rows to incorrectly separate on those commas. How can I account for commas within the strings that I am splitting?

```
      var currentRowOfData = sheet.getRange(j, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();               
      var oneD_array = currentRowOfData.join().split(",")
      destSheet.appendRow(oneD_array)
```

Comment: Use a different join string?

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting one row of data.  You can get the first inner element which is the inner array.

```
var currentRowOfData = sheet.getRange(j, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();               

var oneD_array = currentRowOfData[0];//Get inner array of data

destSheet.appendRow(oneD_array)
```